# Optimize java code to sort array/arraylist with less time

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, comparator

I was writing a program for a quiz which requires me to sort some numbers and print the corresponding string.

For this, I created a class `Song`, and took an array of the objects of this class. I have to sort on the basis of variable `qi`. The problem is that according to the judge, my solution takes too much time and is not efficient enough. I earlier tried with an `ArrayList` of objects and switched to array thinking that could optimize it to an extent but it was of no help.

How can I optimize it further?

My Code:

```
   class Song{
    long fi;
    long qi;
    String si;

    public Song(long fi,String si, long qi){
        this.fi = fi;
        this.si = si;
        this.qi = qi;
    }
}

      public class Zipf {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        long fi;
        long qi;
        String si;
        int noOfSongs = scan.nextInt();
        int selection = scan.nextInt();
        List<Song> list=new ArrayList<Song>(); // all songs
        TreeSet<Song> set = new TreeSet<Song>(new treeComparator());
        for(int i=0; i< noOfSongs;i++)
        {
            fi=(scan.nextLong());
            si=(scan.next());
            qi=(fi*(i+1));
            list.add(new Song(fi,si,qi));//adding all songs to list
        }
        for(int i=0; i< selection;i++)
        {
            set.add(list.get(i));//adding no of songs to be selected into set

        }

        Song min = set.first();
        for (int i = selection; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Song song = list.get(i);
            if (song.qi > min.qi) {
                set.remove(min);
                set.add(song);
                min = set.first();
            }
        }
     Iterator<Song> iterator = set.descendingIterator();

                //Displaying the Tree set data
                for(int i=0;i<selection;i++){
                    System.out.println(iterator.next().si);
                }   

    }


}
class treeComparator implements Comparator<Song>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Song o1, Song o2) {
          if (o1.qi <= o2.qi) return -1;
            if (o1.qi > o2.qi) return 1;
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did your judge complain especially about the sort? Here my only point would be to not create `Long` objects and use `Long.compare(song1.qi, song2.qi)` instead. Maybe there is something else in the code you did not post?

Comment: I tried using Long.compare, but my eclipse showed error. Rest all in my code is just scanning the input and printing based on this sorting.

Comment: How many songs are there to judge/sort?

Comment: Maximum limit is 50000.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the quiz question?

Comment: `treeComparator`'s implementation of `compare` is wrong for the `==` case: if two values are equal, the method must return `0` it currently returns `-1` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29)

Comment: You can avoid creating the `treereverse` object by simply using a `descendingIterator()` on `set`.

Comment: it is the zipf song puzzle in http://labs.spotify.com/puzzles/.

Comment: @Thomas yeah, i did figure that out just after posting this revision. Thanks anyways. Have a look at the link I posted.

Comment: @tgarg You don't need `list` anymore because you can fill `set` directly during scanning. However, one problem with using the above approach is that you lose the natural order of the songs (in which you are supposed to output them). One way to deal with that is to add a field `i` to `Song` and then re-sort the final `set` by `i` just before outputting. A different approach is to use a linked `Song` list of length `selection`, sorted by `i`. Then each time a list entry is replaced, you go through the whole linked list and find the new `min`. But that's actually less efficient in the worst case.

Comment: can there be a possibility that not using java libraries like comparator and TreeSet and implementing everything on my own result in a better efficiency for this problem?
Because I have tried most of the things and I still get the result as time limit exceeded.
I read somewhere that practically these things can result in slower performance in some cases!

Comment: A better data structure than a TreeSet would be a Fibonacci Heap (or similar data structures) because you really only need the operations `insert`, `findMin`, and `deleteMin`. The first two are O(1) in Fibonacci heaps and the last one O(log n), which is slightly better than the costs in a TreeSet. Of course, domain knowledge *can* help to tweak things so that you gain performance, but that will be no principal gain in terms of worst case complexity, "just" constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of Big-O complexity, your solution is optimal. It doesn't matter if you're using an array or an ArrayList, sorting takes O(nlogn) in both cases.

You could optimize in the small, such as avoiding creating new throw-away objects in your `compare` method. But in the big picture this will have a marginal effect on performance.

Thus, are you sure that your general approach to the task is correct? I mean, do you really need to sort the list? For instance, if the task is just to find the minimum `qi`, you could do without sorting the whole list. This can be generalized to the `n` smallest `qi`'s like this:

```
List<Song> list; // all songs
int n; // provided by user

TreeSet<Song> set = new TreeSet<Song>(new Comparator() ...);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    set.add(list.get(i));
}

Song max = set.last();
for (int i = n; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Song song = list.get(i);
    if (song.qi < max.qi) {
        set.remove(max);
        set.add(song);
        max = set.last();
    }
}
```

Here, we assume that the list of songs is very big and that `n` is smaller than the number of songs in the list. As you can see, you don't have to sort the whole list, it's sufficient to iterate over the list linearly once, and only keep the output set sorted.

The `Comparator` is the same that you used in your own code, but you can do without the `new Long` if you do the comparison "manually"

```
public int compare(Song s1, Song s2) {
    if (s1.qi < s2.qi) return -1;
    if (s1.qi > s2.qi) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found no other working way of comparing two long. Using long.compare gave error in eclipse. I do need to sort the elements! I have to print n number of elements in decreasing order.  N is taked from user input.

Comment: Comparison by subtracting brings overflow risk.

Comment: Your edited code is a great help. I will follow this and try again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @assylias Very good point, I got rid of the subtraction. Thanks.

Comment: Or shorter: `return Long.compare(s1.qi, s2.qi);`.

Comment: @assylias Cool - I actually looked for that method in the API docs, but it wasn't there... but now I see it's because it was added in 1.7 and I looked at 1.6 (I don't like the look and feel of more recent API docs and I figured that the method, if anything, would have been there since early versions.)

Comment: @Thomas just a simple correction, you have not considered the case where two qi values are equal.

Comment: @Thomas they still think the solution takes too long. Maybe i am doing something wrong? Would you like to have a look at the complete code?

Comment: @tgarg I think I did consider the case where two qi values are equal. Why do you think otherwise, maybe I overlooked something?

Comment: @tgarg Rather than showing the complete code, perhaps you could insert the complete text of your original quiz task into your question. From the information you gave so far, I don't think I could do it much more efficient than what I posted above, but maybe there's something in the original quiz question that could help me or someone else to improve upon the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `TreeMap` with key as `qi` and value as the object of `Song class`. So that it will be sorted at time of creation. If sorting is your main purpose then go for `TreeSet` and if it requires to fetch data often then `ArrayList` is the good choice.

**EDIT**

`ArrayList` with predetermined `max size` is more faster as it reduces the amount of incremental reallocation. So if you know max number of songs then this will be more faster.

Comment: I need to sort on basis of qi and print si for the n (user input) sorted objects. Will using this be more efficient?

Comment: can please add here which operation is going to happen for more number of time sorting or printing.

Comment: The data structure storing the objects only needs to be sorted once and then on the basis of that, first n sorted object's si is to be printed. I hope I didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: Yes, thats what I wanted to know. So the best choice would be to use `ArrayList`.